# Freeze function arguments inside a function during runtime, python

Tags: python

I would like to freeze one or more function arguments during runtime, by calling a function that freezes these arguments, from another file. I.e imagine I have the following functions:

```
def f1( in_func ):
    in_func()

def f2():
    print('f2')

def freeze_arg(in_func):
    '''Freeze in_func argument f1 to in_func parameter. Redefine f1.'''
```

Is there a way to define the function `freeze_arg` in this example, so that I can call it in **another file**  and change the definition of `f1`. Note that `f1` a `freeze_arg` are defined in the same module. In other words I want to import all the functions above and then call `freez_arg`. A simple implementation like:

```
def freeze_arg(in_func):
    f1 = functools.partial(f1, in_func)
```

won't work because a local `f1` variable will be created that shadows the original `f1` function (and the code crashes as a result). Naively I however expected the following to work:

```
def freeze_arg(in_func):
    global f1
    f1 = functools.partial(f1, in_func)

#in another file
freeze_arg(f2)
f1()
```

But itt throws an error that `f1` expect a positional argument:

> TypeError: f1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'in_func'

Note that this code **does work if the call to freeze_arg happens in the same file**.
Another solution that did not work is the following:

```
frozen_func = None
def freeze_arg(in_func):
    global frozen_func
    frozen_func = functools.partial(f1, in_func)

#in another file:
freeze_args(f2)
f1()
```

throws:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

So my question is: How do I define `freeze_arg` so I can call it after import, and redefine `f1` that way. `f1` is defined in the same file as `freeze_arg`. All of the examples above work when all functions are defined in the same file, but not when importing the functions from another file. A workaround would be to simply reassign the functions outside of the `freeze_arg` function, or to make a class that defines methods that can be used instead of the original function. These workarounds are however not what I am looking for.

Also note that decorators are not an option since they will run at import time and I want to change the function arguments during runtime.

Comment: Assigning to `f1` will *never* affect something in another file. If anything, you want `import other_module`, `other_module.f1 = ...`, which would affect the function in another module. But that all seems like a lot of bending over backwards, and there are surely better design patterns to solve [whatever problem you're trying to solve](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: This is a really bizarre thing to do, and for any possible reason I can think of to do it, there's a much better solution to the underlying problem that doesn't do this bizarre thing. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is not as trivial as people seem to assume. I am building a framework, together with some others, which will be used to build certain neural network architectures. The problem is that the general structure is semi-fixed, but some internal parts must be user-replacable during runtime, and we aim for a functional design. It would be convenient if people can call a single function that replaces a certain part everywhere with their argument. Anyhow, this is not my original question, I simply wonder how to tacke the problem described above.

Comment: "and we aim for a functional design" - but this is a mutative operation, modifying global state. That's not functional design at all. Plus, it changes the call signature of a function dynamically, which seriously messes with any code that needs to call the function.

Comment: The original function is never intended to be called by the user. And yes, this single call does not adhere to a strictly functional paradigm, I understand that.

Comment: We are just exploring different possible avenues of solving a problem. Currently we use a class that basically defines methods that are the reduced versions of the original functions, but it would be nicer without that. Any input on the question would be welcome.

Comment: A class with methods sounds like the way to go, but if you hate classes for some reason, it'd probably make more sense to use a function attribute or a global variable for `in_func`. Plus, it'd make it easier to debug things, or to reconfigure `in_func` after you've already set a value for it.

Comment: About reconfiguring in_func, this is a good point. At the moment with the class factory we can reset it an arbitrary amount of times. Currently it is only ever done once though, so the design in the question seemed like a relevant avenue to try. We might not use it in the end, but are checking options.

Comment: But I would still be interested in a solution to the specific problem, if only out of technical interest.

Comment: The specific issue is covered in my first comment(?). `f1 = ...` in file A will never change `f1` in file B…

Comment: Understood. But would there be a way around this while keeping a similar structure?

Comment: You have read [the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174316/freeze-function-arguments-inside-a-function-during-runtime-python?noredirect=1#comment120490433_68174316)…?

Comment: Yes, and it does not point to an obvious solution, or perhaps I am too stupid to see it. Simply adding the module name i.e. `module.f1 =  ...' in freeze_arg does not work, I explicitly tested it after your comment.

Comment: In general, to modify an attribute/variable/name of another module, that *does* work… I don't know how you tried to apply it exactly, likely there's some mistake there. And your examples are too unclear to provide an exact answer for your code.

Comment: The problem is that f1 and freeze_arg are defined in the same module. I understand that if freeze_arg was in another module where I import f1, I could easily apply your solution. This is however not the case. I explicitly clarified it now in the question.

Comment: If in your *calling* file you have `from other_module import f1`, then reassigning `f1` in `other_module` is also not going to update that previously imported `f1`. You need to call it as `other_module.f1()` too. — In a nutshell, individual *names* like `f1` are never affected when you reassign them elsewhere. You'll need a "parent object", and when accessing it as `other_module.f1`, the updated `f1` will be seen. That's why this seems like such a bad idea, since it forces the caller of the code to adhere to this strict way of importing, which is very unusual.

Comment: Ok thank you for the further explanation. Now I understand the point, and calling it this way explicitly does indeed work. Would you care writing out a solution, which I can then accept?

Comment: Since I don't really like the entire "issue" at all, I'll abstain. Not sure if closing as a duplicate would be more productive, since this particular phenomenon is surely covered _somewhere_ already. But feel free to post a solution if you come up with one.

Comment: Indeed I can imagine the underlying cause is covered somewhere else, but I don't think it is in this context? At least I could not find it after searching for a significant time. If the underlying cause can not be immediately identified by everyone in this context, I would find it strange to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I'll write out a solution then, thank you for your time.

Comment: I have removed the functional programming tag as this has nothing to do with functional programming. Please do not add tags that do not fit the question being asked, you can hover your mouse over the tag to see a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a parameterized class, `my_functor` below. It takes a parameter, `some_param`, and returns a class -

```py
def my_functor(some_param):
  class my_class:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.c = c
    def __str__(self):
      return f"<{some_param}> {self.a} {self.b} {self.c}"

  return my_class
```

Calling `my_functor` builds a new class with a "frozen" parameter -

```py
a_type = my_functor("A")
b_type = my_functor("B")
```

```py
print(a_type("alice", "brenda", "claire"))
print(a_type("denise", "erica", "francisa"))
print(b_type("apple", "berry", "carrot"))
print(b_type("dill", "eggplant", "fennel"))
```

```
<A> alice brenda claire
<A> denise erica francisa
<B> apple berry carrot
<B> dill eggplant fennel
```

---

The class can be parameterized with many parameters of varying types -

```py
def my_functor(some_param, serializer):
  class my_class:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.c = c
    def serialize(self):
      return serializer(f"<{some_param}>", self.a, self.b, self.c)

  return my_class
```

Here's an example with a "stringifying" serializer -

```py
a_type = my_functor("A", lambda *x: ",".join(x))

print(a_type("alice", "brenda", "claire").serialize())
print(a_type("denise", "erica", "francisa").serialize())
```

```
<A>,alice,brenda,claire
<A>,denise,erica,francisa
```

And another type that serializes using a plain list -

```py
b_type = my_functor("B", list)
```

```py
print(b_type("apple", "berry", "carrot").serialize())
print(b_type("dill", "eggplant", "fennel").serialize())
```

```
['<B>', 'apple', 'berry', 'carrot']
['<B>', 'dill', 'eggplant', 'fennel']
```